# Undefined variable in laravel with vue using vform package

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I dont know whats happening with my code in the controller. I just want to send an email based on the select option from my vue component. It just says `undefined variable request`. Im using vform package from vue. But in my controller I already defined the request variable with with the id of the select option from my vue component. But when I put some static email, it can send email and it worked. Can someone know what is the solution? Thanks.

Error in preview in network tab

```
{message: "Undefined variable: request", exception: "ErrorException",…}
exception: "ErrorException"
file: "C:\Users\bustillo-ronald\Desktop\Laravel-SPA\app\Http\Controllers\API\UserController.php"
line: 196
message: "Undefined variable: request"
trace: [,…]
```

My controller

```
    public function sendEmail(Request $request){

        $beautymail = app()->make(\Snowfire\Beautymail\Beautymail::class);
        $beautymail->send('emails.welcome', [], function($message)
         {
            $message
                ->from('test@gmail.com')
                //->to('sampleemail@gmail.com')//this is working with static data
                ->to($request->email)
                ->subject('Welcome!');
        });
    }
```

My vue component with vform

```
           <form @submit.prevent="sendEmail()">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Users Lsit</label>
                            <select v-model="form.email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('email') }">
                                <option  v-for="user in users.data" :key="user.id" >{{user.email}}</option>
                            </select>
                            <has-error :form="form" field="type"></has-error>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Message</label>
                            <textarea v-model="form.message" name="message" placeholder="Message" class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('message') }"></textarea>
                            <has-error :form="form" field="message"></has-error>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Email</button>
                    </div>
                       </form>
```

The script.

```
export default {
        data() {
                return {
                    form: new Form({
                        id:'',
                        email: '',
                        message: ''
                    }),
                    users: []
                }
            },
            methods: {
                getUsers() {
                    axios.get('api/user')
                        .then((res) => {
                            this.users = res.data
                        })
                },
                sendEmail(){
                    this.form.post('api/sendemail')
                          .then(()=>{
                               $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
                               $(".modal-backdrop").remove();

                               swal.fire("Email sent!", "", "success");

                          })
                          .catch((e)=>{
                              console.log(e)
                          })
                }
            },
            created() {
                this.getUsers();
                console.log('Component mounted.')
            }
    }
```

Vue devtools 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not passing the `$request` variable inside the closure.

```
public function sendEmail(Request $request){

    $beautymail = app()->make(\Snowfire\Beautymail\Beautymail::class);
    $beautymail->send('emails.welcome', [], function($message) use($request) // add use($request)
     {
        $message
            ->from('test@gmail.com')
            //->to('sampleemail@gmail.com')//this is working with static data
            ->to($request->email)
            ->subject('Welcome!');
    });
}
```

Comment: wow. Thanks foir your answer sir. It worked for me. Sorry I dont know much about laravel. But thanks a lot really